# Encounter the error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr when compile with clang-cl

Tags: c++, clang, bazel

I'm trying to compile these code with clang-cl with LLVM 15.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    constexpr Foo() = default;
private:
    int i;
};

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;
}
```

The compilation command line is:

```
\> bazel build ... --compiler=clang-cl
```

The error will be displayed

```
cpp-constexpr/main.cpp(4,5): error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr
    constexpr Foo() = default;
    ^
cpp-constexpr/main.cpp(13,9): error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Foo'
    Foo f;
        ^
cpp-constexpr/main.cpp(6,5): note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    ^
2 errors generated.
Target //cpp-constexpr:constexpr failed to build
```

If it is compiled with MSVC 2022/2019, there will be no error at all. Looking forward to known your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like under GCC and clang, `default`ed constructors can't be `constexpr`. I'll have to go Standard diving to find if this is an implementation detail or something mandated by law.

Comment: Or maybe not the Standard: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr#constexpr_constructor

Comment: So, initialize all of the members and you're good to go: https://godbolt.org/z/17x6qTeE5

Comment: And why am I answering in the comments again? Seriously, what's wrong with me?

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the helps!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR version: Compile to C++20 or a more recent version of the C++ Standard where both compilers should accept this code. Downside: you may find other discrepancies between their handling of C++20 and be no better off.

Explanation:

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr#constexpr_constructor)

> for the constructor of a class or struct, every base class sub-object and every non-variant non-static data member must be initialized.

This is valid until C++20. As of C++20, the code should work as presented (but danged if I know what you'll do with a constant uninitialized variable `i`. Have to dig into the Standard or deeper into cppreference to see if `i` is zero initialized or something. [This experiment with Matt Godbolt's compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YPMaWanMM) suggests it's not initialized.

So the fix is most likely to initialize `i`.

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    constexpr Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
private:
    int i = 0;
};
```

MSVC's ability to compile this code prior to C++20 appears to be a bug that could be fixed at any time. Rather than forcing incorrect behaviour onto clang-cl I recommend fixing the code (or compiling both sides to C++20 or more recent.

Comment: Yes, if i is initialized. The compilation is OK for clang-cl. I'm curious is there a compiler flag to mitigate the gap between MSVC with clang-cl. The official document said it is a compatible compiler to MSCV.

Comment: @Erxin clang-cl. Fud. I missed that-cl. Kind of makes my experiment worthless. Anyway, If I'm reading the docs right, unless you're compiling for C++20 or more recent MSVC has a bug and shouldn't accept the code. My suggestion is don't write this code. MSVC allows it today, but you're potentially only one compiler patch away from the bug being fixed. Better to have valid code than invalid compilers.